# How do I use LINQPad with third party plugins?

Tags: c#, linq

All documentation I can find relevant to doing updates with Linqpad mentions a "SubmitChanges" function which should be global for C# code and/or expressions.  Nonetheless it doesn't work;  all I can get is:

The name 'SubmitChanges' does not exist in the current context

This is attempting to use LINQPad with Msoft CRM/Dynamics and the related plugin.  Simple "Select" queries do work.

Comment: Title: "Software Developer"... @Ted, this is supposed to be the title for your question, not *your* title ;)

Comment: That's arguably pretty funny ;-)

Comment: It's the sort of thing which can happen after you've just spent 12 - 14 hours trying to figure out how to do something which should be stone simple like updating a data table with a product hyped to be the greatest thing since women, i.e. your brain sort of turns to mush...

Answer (score 1):

[SubmitChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) is generally only required for 3rd party LINQ providers, such as LINQ to Entities, but not for LINQ to Objects - in that context it will save all the changes made to the underlying data store.

`SubmitChanges()` works on a unit of work such as a [data context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) provided by the LINQ provider, but this doesn't exist for regular LINQ (since all changes are made in memory and don't have to be persisted anywhere).

From MSDN:

> Computes the set of modified objects
>   to be inserted, updated, or deleted,
>   and executes the appropriate commands
>   to implement the changes to the
>   database.

Comment: There actually is a 'SaveChanges' function which is a member of OrganizationServiceContext rather than CRMDataContext and it at least executes, but executing it does not save data.